# How do I build python-nss and NSS for Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, build, nss

I'm trying to build [python-nss](http://people.redhat.com/jdennis/python-nss/doc/api/html/index.html), a python interface for the [Mozilla NSS library](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/), on a 64-bit Mac running Mac OS 10.6.5, for use in python software running on Mac OS X 10.6 or later. I can get NSS itself to build successfully, using certain options, but the python-nss build gives several warnings, and the resulting Python module isn't usable.

To build NSS, I'm following [these instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NSS_reference/Building_and_installing_NSS/Build_instructions), but using this [NSS source code](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_12_9_RTM/src/nss-3.12.9-with-nspr-4.8.7.tar.gz), rather than a checkout from cvs. If I just run `make nss_build_all`, I encounter an error:

```
ncraike@ncraikework ~/Installs/nss-3.12.9/mozilla/security/nss
$ make nss_build_all
...
drbg.c: In function ‘RNG_RandomUpdate’:
drbg.c:516: error: size of array ‘arg’ is negative
make[3]: *** [Darwin10.5.0_DBG.OBJ/Darwin_SINGLE_SHLIB/drbg.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libs] Error 2
make[1]: *** [libs] Error 2
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

The line in question (line 516 of `mozilla/security/nss/lib/freebl/drbg.c`) is an assertion that a particular type is of an expected size:

```
    PR_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(size_t) <= 4);
```

If I write a quick test program, sizeof(size_t) seems to be 8, so perhaps the 64-bit version is being built, despite this on the above instructions page:

> On Unix platforms, except Alpha/OSF1, if you want a build for the system's 64-bit ABI, set USE_64=1 in your environment. By default, NSS builds for the 32-bit environment on all platforms except Alpha/OSF1.

Adding the gcc option `-arch i386` (suggested for a [similar issue](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30670-On-Mac-quot-...file-was-built-for-unsupported-file-format..-quot-SOLVED)) doesn't help, but building with the USE_64 environment variable is successful (although a 64-bit build may not be what I need):

```
ncraike@ncraikework ~/Installs/nss-3.12.9/mozilla/security/nss
$ USE_64=1 make nss_build_all
```

This may be fine, but problems occur when I try to build python-nss (using [this source](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/security/python-nss/releases/PYNSS_RELEASE_0_10_0/src/python-nss-0.10.tar.bz2)).

Some modifications to python-nss's `setup.py` are needed to include the NSS libraries just built. The original `setup.py` hard-codes the include directories for each extension, for example:

```
nss_nss_extension = \
    Extension('nss.nss',
              sources            = ['src/py_nss.c'],
              include_dirs       = ['src', '/usr/include/nss3', '/usr/include/nspr4'],
              libraries          = ['nspr4', 'ssl3', 'nss3'],
              extra_compile_args = extra_compile_args,
              )
```

So I've modified the extension declarations by adding these lines:

```
DIST_ROOT = '/Users/ncraike/Installs/nss-3.12.9/mozilla/dist/'
INCLUDE_DIRS = [DIST_ROOT+'Darwin10.5.0_64_DBG.OBJ/include', DIST_ROOT+'public/nss/', DIST_ROOT+'private/nss/']
LIB_DIRS = [DIST_ROOT+'Darwin10.5.0_64_DBG.OBJ/lib/']
```

...and changing each extension to add an INCLUDE_DIRS list and include a `library_dirs` argument (as described in the [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/distutils/setupscript.html#library-options)). For example:

```
nss_nss_extension = \
    Extension('nss.nss',
              sources            = ['src/py_nss.c'],
              include_dirs       = ['src'] + INCLUDE_DIRS,
              libraries          = ['nspr4', 'ssl3', 'nss3'],
              library_dirs       = LIB_DIRS,
              extra_compile_args = extra_compile_args,
              )
```

After these changes, `python setup.py build` runs and seems to be aware of the NSS libraries, but produces several warnings, including:

```
src/py_nss.c:12640: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘Py_ssize_t’
gcc-4.2 -Wl,-F. -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/src/py_nss.o -L/Users/ncraike/Installs/nss-3.12.9/mozilla/dist/Darwin10.5.0_64_DBG.OBJ/lib/ -lnspr4 -lssl3 -lnss3 -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/nss/nss.so
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/src/py_nss.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /Users/ncraike/Installs/nss-3.12.9/mozilla/dist/Darwin10.5.0_64_DBG.OBJ/lib//libnspr4.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /Users/ncraike/Installs/nss-3.12.9/mozilla/dist/Darwin10.5.0_64_DBG.OBJ/lib//libssl3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

"file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked" is the most common warning. This error is mentioned in [a post on another site](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30670-On-Mac-quot-...file-was-built-for-unsupported-file-format..-quot-SOLVED), with a possible solution of using the `-arch i386` option with gcc. I'm not sure at what step in the build process to add this option (NSS or python-nss?), and how I might add it to the python distutils build script.

The build does complete, but the resulting python module doesn't seem usable:

```
ncraike@ncraikework ~/Installs/python-nss-0.10/build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6
$ ls
nss
ncraike@ncraikework ~/Installs/python-nss-0.10/build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6
$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nss.nss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(nss/nss.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/libssl3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ncraike/Installs/python-nss-0.10/build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/nss/nss.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Is my error in how I'm building NSS or how I'm building python-nss? How should I be telling the python-nss build script to link with the Mac OS X NSS libraries correctly? I have much more python experience than C experience, so if I've made some simple building  error I won't be surprised.

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.5, with Xcode 3.2.4 (64-bit) installed. `gcc -v` gives `gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)` and `Target: i686-apple-darwin10`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX 10.7 we have llvm-gcc and llvm-g++ by default. They usually print out more verbal error messages.

```
cc -o Darwin11.3.0_DBG.OBJ/Darwin_SINGLE_SHLIB/drbg.o -c -g -fPIC -Di386 -Wmost -fpascal-strings -fno-common -pipe -DDARWIN -DHAVE_STRERROR -DHAVE_BSD_FLOCK  -DXP_UNIX -DSHLIB_SUFFIX=\"dylib\" -DSHLIB_PREFIX=\"lib\" -DSHLIB_VERSION=\"3\" -DSOFTOKEN_SHLIB_VERSION=\"3\" -DRIJNDAEL_INCLUDE_TABLES -DDEBUG -UNDEBUG -DDEBUG_antkong -DUSE_UTIL_DIRECTLY -DMP_API_COMPATIBLE -I../../../../dist/Darwin11.3.0_DBG.OBJ/include -I../../../../dist/public/nss -I../../../../dist/private/nss -Impi -Iecl  drbg.c
drbg.c:471:34: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'PRStatus' to different enumeration type 'SECStatus' (aka 'enum _SECStatus') [-Wconversion]
    return (globalrng != NULL) ? PR_SUCCESS : PR_FAILURE;
                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~
drbg.c:471:47: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'PRStatus' to different enumeration type 'SECStatus' (aka 'enum _SECStatus') [-Wconversion]
    return (globalrng != NULL) ? PR_SUCCESS : PR_FAILURE;
                               ~              ^~~~~~~~~~
drbg.c:516:5: error: 'arg' declared as an array with a negative size
    PR_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(size_t) <= 4);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../dist/Darwin11.3.0_DBG.OBJ/include/prtypes.h:528:42: note: expanded from macro 'PR_STATIC_ASSERT'
    extern void pr_static_assert(int arg[(condition) ? 1 : -1])
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

Hopefully they may help you to find a solution or file a bug report with Mozilla NSS project